# Google Sheet to Laravel 8 Integration

Tags: laravel, google-sheets, laravel-8

I want to integrate **google sheet with Laravel 8** without any third party tool or connector. I know its simple for many but i am not able to get through. Highly appreciate for your effort and answers!

Answer (score 16):

##### Requirements:

- Google OAuth Keys.
- Google Service Account.
- Enabling Google Drive API and Google Sheets API.
- `revolution/laravel-google-sheets` Laravel package.

###### Steps:

###### Step 1: Installing revolution/laravel-google-sheets package

```
composer require revolution/laravel-google-sheets

# publish package files
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="PulkitJalan\Google\GoogleServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

###### Step 2: Setup Google API OAuth Key

- Navigate to [Google Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/console)
- Create a Google project or select already existed project.
- Click **Create credentials** followed by **OAuth client ID**.
- If necessary, **Configure consent screen**.
- Set the type to **Web Application**.
- Copy client_id and client_secret and set in .env:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

###### Step 3: Setup Google Service Account

- Navigate to [Google Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/console)
- Create a new Service account key from Credentials.
- Give your service account a name.
- Under `Grant this service account access to project` step click on **Select a Role** dropdown and choose **Project** from left side and **Editor** from right side as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmaOY.png)
- Click **Continue** then **Done**.
- Edit the service account and go to Keys tab.
- Create a new Key of type **JSON**, and copy the json file to your project storage directory and rename it as `credentials.json` -or any other name you like.
- Add credentials.json file path to .env as following

```
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ENABLED=true
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION=/home/user/code/project/storage/credentials.json
```

###### Step 4: Setup a Google Spreadsheet to integrate with

- Create/Open a Google Spreadsheet file.
- Give the sheet a name
- Copy the ID of the document from file URL (e.g. [https://docs.gogle.com/spreadsheets/d/{{SPREADSHEET_ID}}](https://docs.gogle.com/spreadsheets/d/%7B%7BSPREADSHEET_ID%7D%7D)), see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVuYK.png)
- Set the document id you copied in last step to .env

```
SPREADSHEET_ID=1kjtQBxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

- Copy the **Email** of the recently created **Service Account**, see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7ZB6.png)
- **Share** the sheet with the **Service Account** email as **Editor**, see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeRox.png)

###### Step 5: Enable required Google APIs

- Navigate to [Google Developers Console APIs Dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard).
- Click **ENABLE API AND SERVICES**.
- Search for `Google Drive API` and **Enable** it.
- Search for `Google Sheets API` and **Enable** it.

###### Step 6: Test it

```
use Revolution\Google\Sheets\Facades\Sheets;

// Add new sheet to the configured google spreadsheet
Sheets::spreadsheet(config('sheets.spreadsheet_id'))->addSheet('sheetTitle');

$rows = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['4', '5', '6'],
    ['7', '8', '9'],
];

// Append multiple rows at once
Sheets::sheet('sheetTitle')->append($rows);
```

see the package documentation for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer . I had to add the scopes as mentioned in Harry Bosh's answer, and everything's working.

Answer (score 7):

```
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "errors": [ { "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }
```

Dont forget to add  scopes!

`[\Google\Service\Sheets::DRIVE, \Google\Service\Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]`

to the google.php config file